# mysql how to use JOIN instead of IN with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please help me with below query in which i use IN clause which Leads performance issue. I want to use JOIN for it but not sure how for do for such query.

```
select * 
from user_followings 
where followed_id = 'xyz' AND owner_id IN (
   select DISTINCT owner_id 
   from feed_events 
   where DTYPE = 'PLAYLIST' AND last_updated_timestamp > '20-04-2017' AND (feed_type = 'PLAYED_PLAYLIST' OR feed_type = 'STARTED_LISTENING') 
   order by last_updated_timestamp DESC)";
```

Comment: Do the examples in the [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)  not help ?

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? What are the challenges you are facing?

Comment: @money Yes, i tried but here my main concern is not to get query I also want to know how to choose clause for specific requirement and what will be the best option to get faster response form queries.

Comment: Then probably you should update your OP from How to use JOIN to when/Why to use JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your query using join:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM user_followings
    INNER JOIN feed_events ON user_followings.owner_id = feed_events.owner_id
    WHERE followed_id = 'xyz'
        AND DTYPE = 'PLAYLIST'
        AND feed_events.last_updated_timestamp > '20-04-2017'
        AND (
            feed_type = 'PLAYED_PLAYLIST'
            OR feed_type = 'STARTED_LISTENING'
            )
    ORDER BY last_updated_timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Dave for query but it gives an Error "Column 'last_updated_timestamp' in where clause is ambiguous".

Answer (score 1):

A `join` probably is not the best approach.  Use `exists`:

```
select uf.* 
from user_followings uf
where uf.followed_id = 'xyz' and
      exists (select 1
              from feed_events fe
              where uf.owner_id = fe.owner_id and
                    fe.DTYPE = 'PLAYLIST' and
                    fe.last_updated_timestamp > '2017-04-20' and
                    fe.feed_type in ('PLAYED_PLAYLIST', 'STARTED_LISTENING') 
             );
```

You want an index on `feed_events(owner_id, dtype, last_updated_timestamp, feed_type)` and `user_followings(followed_id, owner_id)`.

Other notes:

- `ORDER BY` in such a subquery is useless.
- Use standard date formats (YYYY-MM-DD) for constant dates.
- Use `IN` instead of a bunch of `OR`s.  It is easier to read and optimizes better under most circumstances.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, for explanation. I have to create more complex queries this knowledge help me :)